# Angular / JADE - Why am I receiving the error "Unexpected token {" when trying to use an Angular tag in a ng-href attribute?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, pug

Here's my code:

```
extends layout

block content
h1= title
p User Directory

// Wrapper
#wrapper

    input(type='text', placeholder='Search Users...')
    h2 User List

    // USER LIST
    div(ng-controller='UserListCtrl')
      #UserList
          table
              thead
                  th UserName
                  th DOB
              tbody
                tr(ng-repeat='user in users')
                  td: a(ng-href='/users/{{user.id}}')= {{user.fc}}
                  td {{user.birthYear}}
    // /USER LIST

// /WRAPPER
```

The line with the anchor tag is returning an "Unexpected token {" error. I've tried many variations; using just href, concatenating the string, etc. I'm literally just starting off learning this so please forgive any ignorance on my part if I'm making a simple mistake.

Comment: `{{user.fc}}` should be string, any proper editor will highlight it straight away

Comment: Oh I see. What would be the best way to output the int as a string?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ?

```
td: a(ng-href='/users/'+{{user.id}})= {{user.fc}}
```